# Compare change in biomarker in two groups at two timepoints - which test should I use?

Tags: repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

Here is a question for which I did not find a definitive answer here.
So suppose I have two non-randomised group (i.e. observational data), A and B. I have measured a biomarker (named "C") over two timepoints (T0 and T1).

I want to test whether the change in "C" concentrations over the two timepoints (T0->T1) is different between the two groups (A vs. B); in other words, I want to test whether there is a difference in the change of the biomarker C between the two groups, across the two timepoints.

Which test should I use? I am not sure ANCOVA on T1 values with T0 values as covariate would be ideal in this setting, so would like to ask for more opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Difference in difference was made for this sort of thing.  Let $t$ be a binary variable with 0 indicating time point 0 and 1 indicating time point 1. Let $g$ be a binary variable with 0 indicating group A and 1 indicating group B.  The model

$$ C = \beta_0 + \beta_1  t + \beta_2 g +  \beta_3 t \times g + \epsilon$$

is interpreted as follows:

- $\beta_0$ is the average biomarker measure for group A in time point 0
- $\beta_1$ is the average difference in biomarker measure between group B and group A
- $\beta_2$ is the average difference in biomarker measure in group A between time points 1 and 0
- $\beta_3$ is the average difference in biomarker measure in group B between time points 1 and 0.

If the test for coefficient $\beta_3$ rejects the null, then the data are consistent group B changing differently in time as compared to group A.

Comment: So you are suggesting to perform a regression in which I "manually" model the individual terms as you explained, is that right?

Comment: @user89547235 If you fit a regression with a main effect of time and group, and their interaction, this is the interpretation. I would suggest the regression approach because it most easily estimates the quantity you’re after — namely, the difference in changes over time.